# How to solve ALSA lib error with raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I have the below code for speech recognition:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()

print("Start talking!")

while True:
    with mic as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
    words = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print(words)
```

I got the below error:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:638:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1075:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
```

How can I solve this error please?